# OSGI Bundle: ConfigurationAdmin truncates key when there is an "=" in it

Tags: java, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I have an OSGI Bundle running in Karaf. My bundle retrieves through the ConfigurationAdmin all the configurations.
I iterate all the configurations to get the properties.

I have a problem with a property's key. 
The property has this key - value

> "setStartLevel(java.lang.String, = int)[/([1-4])?[0-9]/,/.*/] = admin"

As you can see there is an "=" inside the key(just before "int").

The ConfigurationAdmin gives me back:

> KEY="setStartLevel(java.lang.String, "

and

> VALUE="int)[/([1-4])?[0-9]/,/.*/] = admin"

This is my code, I simply retrieve properties:

```
configs = this.configurationAdmin.listConfigurations(null);
for (Configuration cfg : configs) {
        Dictionary<String, Object> properties = cfg.getProperties();
        Collections.list(properties.keys()).forEach(key -> {
            System.out.println("KEY: "+key);
            System.out.println("VALUE: "+properties.get(key));
                 }
        }
```

Any idea to how tell ConfigurationAdmin to retrieve the right key-value?

Answer (score 0):

Escape the first "=" with a backslash "\"

```
 % cat io.hyte.foo.cfg 
 hello=world
 foo\=bar=blah
```

Confirm values within Karaf

```
   karaf@root()> config:list "(service.pid=io.hyte.foo)"
   ----------------------------------------------------------------
   Pid:            io.hyte.foo
   BundleLocation: ?
   Properties:
       felix.fileinstall.filename = file:...etc/io.hyte.foo.cfg
       foo=bar = blah
       hello = world
       service.pid = io.hyte.foo
```

UPDATED:

A couple options to support the "can't enforce the character escaping" problem:

1. Update and re-write the keys in the configuration to be properly escaped.

-- or --

2. Look into registering a org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationPlugin that can then modify the keys (this would only apply to managed services, not general bundles using ConfigurationAdmin).

Comment: Hi Matt, Thank you for your reply. What I was looking for is something on Java side to fix this problem. I cannot ask a user to manage all the config properties with an "=" on it. Since I retrive the configurations that are already in the container(my bundle can be installed in any OSGI container) I can only manage them inside my bundle.